# Google Map Places Auto-complete blocked by jQuery Mobile popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-places-api

It is easier to see what I mean by looking at this image:
http://postimg.org/image/fcmo6pbvp/

I am trying to let the user input the address using the google maps places auto-complete JS function like this [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform).

It works, but the autocomplete text field, is blocked by the jQuery Mobile popup, just like the picture shown.

The HTML Look something like this:

```
            <li>

                <a href="#popupLocation" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window"
                    class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-a" data-transition="pop">
                    <h3>Location</h3>
                    <p id="locationSelectionString">London, UK</p>
                </a>


                <div data-role="popup" id="popupLocation" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all">

                        <div style="padding:10px 20px;">
                            <h3 style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">Location</h3>
                            <hr>
                            <table width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <input id="locationSelectionInput" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" name="location" value="" placeholder="Enter a location" data-theme="a" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="50%">
                                        <button style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;" onclick="changeLocationCanceled();">Cancel</button>
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="50%">
                                        <button style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;" onclick="changeLocation();">OK</button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </li>
```

I will be so happy if someone can tell me what went wrong.

BTW, don't laugh at my code, this is my first JS app :p

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle with your code?

Comment: the code looks ugly but here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/christinalam/L7xt97qc/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's too late for Christina. I hope to help other people struggling this issue.

My solution is just in you css file add code.

```
.pac-container{
    z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```